# How do I write a function starting with the keywork const - JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, function, console, constants

I hope you are well.

I am very new to coding and I am trying to complete a challenge where I have to create a function and output the following to console:

```
The weather in Scotland is sunny
The weather in Spain is glorious
The weather in Poland is cold
=> undefined
```

The part I am not getting is that the brief asks me to start with the keyword 'const' (then the const name). 
I have written the following which outputs what is required but I'm not sure if this is correct.

```
function getWeather (country, weatherType) {
  console.log('The weather in ' + country + ' is ' + weatherType);
}

getWeather('Scotland', 'sunny');
getWeather('Spain', 'glorious');
getWeather('Poland', 'cold');
```

I am being asked in the brief to write a function with two parameters (country & weatherType) and then have two arguments (the name of a country & the type of weather).

I will output this to console in the format 'The weather in 'country' is 'type of weather.

Any help would be appreciated.
Many thanks.

Comment: um... `const getWeather = function (.....`

Comment: Do some reading up on the terms *"function expression"* and *"function declaration"*

Comment: Thanks for the feedback people. I'm on it.

Answer (score 2):

`Functions` are first class citizens in JS means it can be assigned to variable and passed as argument or return a function from function, so you can assign a function to variable and use it

[`First class function MDN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/First-class_Function)

```js
const getWeather = function (country, weatherType) {
  console.log('The weather in ' + country + ' is ' + weatherType);
}

getWeather('Scotland', 'sunny');
getWeather('Spain', 'glorious');
getWeather('Poland', 'cold');
```

Comment: Ok I see where I was going wrong Code Maniac .

'Assign a function to a variable' was the clincher in your statement.

I had a variation but the sytax was wrong.
I was getting there.

Thanks for your help and to all for the suggestions.
You live and learn ...I did say I was very new :)